# Obtain different launcher items with .desktop files running the same executable

Tags: 14.04, .desktop, launcher

Suppose you need different launchers to run the same application, as in S1.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=S1
Comment=Open a terminal with ssh connection to S1
Exec=gnome-terminal --maximize --tab --command 'ssh Server1'
Icon=/home/usr/Desktop/.S1.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

and S2.desktop:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=S2
Comment=Open a terminal with ssh connection to S2
Exec=gnome-terminal --maximize --tab --command 'ssh Server2'
Icon=/home/usr/Desktop/.S2.png
Terminal=false
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

Then whenever you launch S1, then S2, the launcher icon referring to S2 goes grouped with S1 icon. However, you'd like to have two different icons in the launcher, so that you're able to switch immediately between the two windows (terminals all look the same when they are small and you can't read the command line header 'cause it's too small). How can one achieve that?